# How can I remove "Add" popup functionality in Django?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a app that crashes Internet Explorer when clicked in an "Add" button in Django Admin.
It is a way to remove this popup functionality from Django?

Comment: By IE, which IE do you mean? I'd say let it crash for anything earlier than IE9, unless you really need to support older versions.

Comment: give us some more context

Comment: @melwil The version of IE is less than 9, but this is not the case.

When I click in Add, open the Popup Window(Web Dialog) and try to load and dont stop until the IE crashes, and then I must restart all IE.
 
What I need to know if there is any way to remove the Popup functionality from Django?

Comment: Do you still need the ability to add objects? Because you can disable "Add" entirely in Django.

Comment: I would like to do a validation.
In the case of IE8-, redirect to a new window, otherwise the functionality runs normally.
But I do not know which files to validating this.

@SimeonVisser If you can tell me how to remove all functionality, I already know how to solve the problem adding a new button to set new objects in a new window.